# lua: init.lua:15: attempt to call method 'alarm' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, esp8266

i am trying to fix a piece of code i did find online. (yeah i know....)
But in case you guys can help me out wihth this error it would be just amazing:

Error: lua: init.lua:15: attempt to call method 'alarm' (a nil value)

Code (from here: https://github.com/Christoph-D/esp8266-wakelight)

```
dofile("globals.lc")

wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD)
wifi.sta.sethostname(MY_HOSTNAME)
if WIFI_STATIC_IP then
  wifi.sta.setip({ip = WIFI_STATIC_IP, netmask = WIFI_NETMASK, gateway = WIFI_GATEWAY})
end
wifi.sta.connect()

-- Initialize the LED_PIN to the reset state.
gpio.mode(LED_PIN, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.write(LED_PIN, gpio.LOW)

tmr.alarm(
  MAIN_TIMER_ID, 2000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function ()
    if wifi.sta.getip() then
      tmr.unregister(MAIN_TIMER_ID)
      print("Config done, IP is " .. wifi.sta.getip())
      dofile("ledserver.lc")
    end
  end)
```

What can i do there? Whats wrong?

Cheers and thank you!!!

Comment: rather certain you cant call `alarm` like that, as it is not a value in `tmr`. it is a metamethod for a timer object. https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/tmr/#tobjalarm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all in the manual. You just have to read it.

There is an example of how to use the alarm method of timer objects.

```
if not tmr.create():alarm(5000, tmr.ALARM_SINGLE, function()
  print("hey there")
end)
then
  print("whoopsie")
end
```

You attempted to call `tmr.alarm` but it is `tobj:alarm`. The manual does not mention `tmr.alarm`. This function was removed from NodeMCU in January 2019.

You're using code you found online that is basedn on an older NodeMCU version. It is using functions that are deprecated by now.

See https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2603#issuecomment-453235401

and

https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/compare/5b22e1f9aee77095ab99dd6240ebd9dddd1cc5a0..c6444ecb6088d20e95197d808d8303c8093faab5

So you have to create a timer object first befvor you can use any of its methods. `alarm` is not a method of the `tmr` module anymore.

---

**Edit**

First you have to create a timer object https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tmr/#tobjcreate

```
local tObj = tmr.create()
```

Then you have to [register](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tmr/#tobjregister) a callback and [start](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tmr/#tobjstart) the timer. There is a convenience function [alarm](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tmr/#tobjalarm) that does both for us.

And when we do not need our timer anymore we have to free the resources by calling

```
tObj:unregister()
```

Try something like

```
-- create a timer object
local tObj = tmr.create()
-- register an alarm
tObj:alarm(2000, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function ()
    if wifi.sta.getip() then
      tObj:unregister()
      print("Config done, IP is " .. wifi.sta.getip())
      dofile("ledserver.lc")
    end
  end)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It seems that this will be a bit too hard for me with my little knowledge of nodemcu... Is there any way to find an old nodemcu firmware with my desired components? Thanks!!

Comment: Or could you maybe provide me with one example how i would translate lines like this to the current version of NodeMCU? I could then try to understand what i have to do ;) 

"  tmr.alarm(
    MAIN_TIMER_ID, 300, tmr.ALARM_AUTO, function ()"